# Чем отличается программист-техник от программиста-инженера?

Tags: работа

Чем отличается программист-техник от программиста-инженера?

Comment: А где вы заметили подобную градацию?

Comment: В колледже программист-техник, а в университете есть программист-инженер

Comment: в табеле, в трудовой.

Comment: По конкретнее, хотелось бы больше узнать об этих двух специальностях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зарплатой. Грубо говоря, программист-инженер решает задачи на более высоком уровне. Программист-техник = кодер, тестер или еще что-то в этом же духе. А все проистекает из того, что техник - у нас это тот, кто имеет проф. среднее, а инженер - высшее образование.

Comment: Если брать Гос. структуры, то инженер подразумевает наличие или учебу в ВУЗ, техник это колледж и не более. В тех же гос. структурах вы практически никогда не получите инженера, если нет высшего, а если брать коммерцию, то, как сказал gecube, разница только в зарплате.